# Inner Automorphisms of a Lie Subalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras, automorphism-group

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{h}\subseteq\mathfrak{g}$ a subalgebra. If $\tau$ is an inner automorphism of $\mathfrak{h}$, can we always lift $\tau$ to an inner automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$? If not, what additional hypotheses are needed?

Comment: The word is not "lift" but "extend". Would you first provide a definition of inner automorphism (for arbitrary Lie algebras over arbitrary fields??)?